# binding.PBKDF2 error when hashing passwords Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, encryption, pbkdf2

I am trying to hash my passwords in the user model with `crypto.PBKDF2` but my validatePassword method is failing with the following exception

> return binding.PBKDF2(password, salt, iterations, keylen, digest, callback);

This is the full error

```
crypto.js:562
return binding.PBKDF2(password, salt, iterations, keylen, digest, callback);
               ^
TypeError: Not a buffer
    at TypeError (native)
    at pbkdf2 (crypto.js:562:20)
    at Object.exports.pbkdf2Sync (crypto.js:553:10)
    at new <anonymous> (c:\Users\Joseph\news-trends\models\Users.js:25:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Joseph\news-trends\models\Users.js:24:39)
    at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Joseph\news-trends\app.js:17:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:398:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:405:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
```

These are the relevant methods

```
UserSchema.methods.setPassword = function(password){
    var self = this;

    crypto.randomBytes(16, function(err, salt){
        if(err){ throw err; }
        self.salt = salt.toString('hex');
    });

    crypto.pbkdf2(password, this.salt, 1000, 64, function(err, hash){
        if(err){ throw err;}
        self.hash = hash.toString('hex');
    });
};
UserSchema.methods.validatePassword = new function(password){
    var hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');
    return this.hash = hash;
};
```

Here is a link to the full code: [Repo](https://github.com/MultiplisJoseph/news-trends)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is somewhat confusing, it sets a variable to an asynchronous function, and somehow tries to use that inside the function?

`crypto` methods have a callback where the generated key is the second argument, and this is how you'd generally use them

```
UserSchema.methods.setPassword = function(password){

    var self = this;

    crypto.randomBytes(16, function(err, salt){
        if(err){ throw err; }
        self.salt = salt.toString('hex');
    });

    crypto.pbkdf2(password, this.salt, 1000, 64, function(err, hash){
        if(err){ throw err;}
        self.hash = hash.toString('hex');
    });
}

UserSchema.methods.validatePassword = function(password){
    var hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');
    return this.hash === hash;
};
```

Note that your `setPassword` and `validatePassword` methods only works for one instance, which is probably fine for testing, but if you want more than one user, you probably need a database to hold those values, and not just assign them to `this`.

The error you're getting is because you're trying to pass the returned result from the asynchronous functions to `new Buffer`, and not the generated keys

Comment: I added your code and changed the question accordingly. I also changed the pbkdf2Sync method but the error still exists @adeneo

Comment: @MultiplisJoseph - try to at least remove the `new` keyword in front of that function in the last part.

Answer (score 2):

I know its late, But if anyone is still facing this issue, this is what i did, and it solved my issue.

```
UserSchema.methods.setPassword = function(password){
    this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
    this.hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');
}

UserSchema.methods.validatePassword = function(password){
    var hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');
    return this.hash === hash;
};
```